# Offline installation for pip packages fails with error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement"

Tags: python, pip

In order to make packages installed offline, I use the -d (or --download) option to `pip install`. For instance, `pip install --download dependencies -r requirements.txt` will download the packages for all required dependencies mentioned in `requirements.txt` to `dependencies` dir (but will not install them). Then I use `pip install --no-index --find-links dependencies -r requirements.txt` to install those downloaded packages without accessing the network.

Most of the time it works fine, but sometimes installation fails with error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xyz". After doing `pip install --user xyz --find-links dependencies` manually (xyz IS present in the dependencies folder), installation fails with the same "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement abc" error, but with different package 'abc'. It repeats several times until I manually resolve all failed dependencies.

How could I make run `pip install --no-index --find-links dependencies -r requirements.txt` without those weird dependency errors not finding packages that are already there?

Comment: have you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of two things:

1. The `pip` version is the same in the offline server and in the online one.

   - To find out: `pip -V`
   - To update (if needed): `pip install --upgrade pip`
2. The python version is the same in both virtual enviroments or servers.

   - To find out: `python` (the header will have the version info)

In my case I was calling `pip install --download` outside the virtual environment (using default python version - 2.7) and then installing in a virtual environment with python 3 and the error I got was exactly the one you mentioned.